# Can I use php and javascript create form edit data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create form for edit data from MySQL with javascript. when I click link Edit it will show edit form for edit data.

This is from and php code for show data.

```
<form id="form-edit" method="post">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE question_id = $question_id ORDER BY id DESC";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while($cm = mysqli_fetch_array($r1)) {

        $comment_id = $cm['id'];

        echo '<section class="section-comment">';
        echo '<span class="commentator">' .$cm['user_id'] . '</span>';
        echo $cm['detail'];

        // This is link Edit
        echo '<a href="#" class="edit-comment" edit-id="'.$comment_id.'">Edit</a>';

        echo $comment_id;  //This can show correct comment_id

        ?>

        <div id="form-edit-dialog">


    <input type="text" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id ?>" readonly > <br> 

    //I add this line for check comment_id but it show max comment_id to min when I open and close form
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $comment_id ?>" readonly > <br>  

    <textarea name="detail"></textarea><br>

    <button type="submit" id="submit-edit">Submit</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment-id">

}
</form>
</div>
```

I write code java script like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.edit-comment').click(function(event) {   //Click link Edit
        $('#form-edit')[0].reset();

        event.preventDefault();

        var t = "Edit Comment";

        $('#form-edit-dialog').dialog({
            width: '600px',
            title: t,
            modal: true,
            position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window}
        });

        //set value for hidden 
        $('#comment-id').val($(this).attr('edit-id'));

    });

    $('#submit-edit').click(function() { 

        $('form#form-edit').ajaxForm({
            url: 'save-edit.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'script',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $.blockUI({message:'<h3>Sending data...</h3>'});
            }, 
            complete: function() {

                $.unblockUI();
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

PHP can list all comment and show comment_id correctly but when I click at  Edit ,  it show max number of comment_id and when I close form and click Edit again. The comment_id will reduce comment_id number untill no comment_id.
Can I use php and javascript create form edit data or I have to send data to new page?

Answer (score 0):

1. if the user has the right to comment it means he is logged, so basically you can get the id from session, cookie; doesn't make sens to extract here the user id OR you can make the check if he has the right to comment ( user_id is same with session one).
2. just make the switch between  and  like this:

<

```
<div id="showtext<?php echo $comment_id ?>" >
<span id="comment<?php echo $comment_id ?>"><?php echo $cm['detail'] ?></span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit-comment" id="<?php echo $comment_id ?>">Edit</a>
<div>

<!-- this is invisible at start -->
<div id="showedit<?php echo $comment_id ?>"  style="display:none">
<textarea id="edittext<?php echo $comment_id ?>"><?php echo $cm['detail'] ?></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="submit-comment" id="<?php echo $comment_id ?>">Save comment</a>
</div>
```

and javascript to toggle views:

```
 $('.edit-comment').click(function() {  
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
$("#showedit"+id).show();
$("#showtext"+id).hide();
});
```

and to submit

```
  $('.submit-comment').click(function() {  
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var comment=$("#edittext"+id).val();

    //send the data via ajax with parameters id and comment to alter the row, in php add the user id from session, cookie and on success:

//replace the old text
    $("#comment"+id).html(comment);
//and make the switchback
    $("#showedit"+id).hide();
    $("#showtext"+id).show();

    })
```